# How to reduce power consumption on laptop when running Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, laptop

I am having Ubuntu 10.04 on my laptop.

The battery doesn't last as long as it does when on Windows.

Any thing we can do to improve it ?

Its a Lenovo Y410 notebook with core 2 duo processor and 2 GB of RAM

Comment: What laptop is this? Ubuntu may not have the right ACPI drivers, which means that it can't help the computer manage power.

Answer (score 2):

While slightly outdated, the [Gentoo Power Management Guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/power-management-guide.xml) is a good resource.